# Nvidia GPU not detecting displays

Tags: display

Having problems with NVIDIA GPU not detecting displays properly.
I have 1 external monitor, and a laptop screen
Using Elementary Freya 0.3 x64 and NVIDIA binary driver 355.06, everything is up to date.

Resolutions:

- laptop: 1366x768
- monitor: 1360x768

both monitors support 60Hz refresh rate, but their refresh rates are much lower, I'm noticing some slight mouse pointer delay.

xorg.conf ad xrand: [xorg_xrandr_pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BinwALwW)

X Server Display Configuration Layout is following:
[image]

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
```

- > 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
- > 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M] [10de:1050] (rev a1)

Anyone has any idea what could be causing this, maybe faulty GPU or something ?
Integrated Intel is detecting everything properly.

I've also tried manually configuring xorg, but I can't seem to find any decent way to set up refresh rate, since all the command I've been able to dig up on google are using deprecated commands etc. so I'd appreciate if someone has an idea/way to manually configure the layout.

Thanks.

Comment: Please,  can you post model and vendor monitor?

Comment: [samsung syncmaster 933](http://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-syncmaster-933sn-lcd-monitor-18-5-series/specs/)

Comment: please did u solve this problem? I have exactly the same on my notebook, I tried everything but nothing works. I changes xorg.conf in all possible ways but nothing makes changes. I am running nvidia driver 352.63 with Nvidia GTX860M Thank you very much!

Comment: How did you install the drivers? From the Additional Drivers window or by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

This message in the picture :

```
X Screen 0 (No Scanout)
```

makes me think that xorg is not detecting your monitor vendor.

Connect the monitor to the laptop, start it and login. Try the buttons on the monitor,  enter in the OSD menu, go to SETUP > Reset.

After this, go to Configuration > Displays in your desktop. Monitor will go to blank for one second and you will see the correct resolution and your monitor vendor.

Comment: Doesn't help, Nvidia X server's still not recognizing the layout. The system's display settings detect the monitor and resolution, but doesn't allow me to change the samsung monitor to primary monitor.

Comment: If you are using a VGA connector to attach the monitor, the system identifies as CTR. Your xorg configuration don't allow CTR monitors. Change it in Screen section, option "IgnoreDisplayDevices". Feedback will aprecciated.

Comment: After removing that line, it manages to detect this, at first login:
[firstLogin](http://i.imgur.com/gUKth1C.jpg)

I'm able to set refresh rate and resolution on samsung.


When I open Freya's display settings, this happens
(I've wanted to set samsung as primary monitor)

[freya settings](http://i.imgur.com/tUIlAer.jpg)

Comment: Sorry but it seems the same pic in both links

Comment: yea, my bad, didn't notice.
here's the 2nd picture
http://i.imgur.com/ROkWPE1.jpg

Comment: update: at the situation from 2nd link, when I try to set up samsung as main display, it goes back to normal, but nvidia x-server settings is still detecting CRT-0 only, which makes it impossible to split screens. Perhaps full manual xorg config will manage to force the layout ?

Comment: Also try to remove proprietary drivers and install Nouveau. Lets Freya display config make the work.

Comment: Installed noveau, logged in, tried to change default GPU used to display, got this [link](http://i.imgur.com/pEkUDxg.jpg)

Comment: Select your monitor from Configuration > Displays

Comment: THe layout works fine, but as I've linked, when I try to switch to nvidia gpu, I get that error. Only way I can switch to nvidia gpu is with nvidia drivers, but then I'm having the layout problem as described in original question.

Comment: Only way with Nvidia drivers is a custom xorg.conf

Comment: will try it tomorrow/these days, will post the results

Comment: Got this issue now, anything?